# error: 'RFC2822Date' is not a member of 'Qt'

Tags: c++, qt5, ubuntusdk

Компилятор ругается на следующий код:

```
mime += QString("Date: %1\r\n").arg(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(Qt::RFC2822Date));
                                                                          ^
error: 'RFC2822Date' is not a member of 'Qt'
```

Инклуды делал по отдельности и вместе:

```
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDate>
```

Работаю на UbuntuSDK-QT5, С++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ходе обсуждения проблемы в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37655/discussion-between-gil9red-and-shaman888), выяснилось, что у автора версия сборки автоматически собиралась под `Qt 4`, в которой [Qt::RFC2822Date](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#DateFormat-enum) нет.

Comment: Добавил, не помогло.

Comment: У вас точно `Qt5`? У меня на `Qt4` не находит, а в `Qt5` находит

Comment: Based on QT 5.4.2

Comment: Окей, чем собираете? Какая IDE?

Comment: UbuntuSDK - это QT Creator 3.5

Comment: Раз Qt Creator, то: Откройте Tools/Option/Build & Run вкладка Qt versions

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37655/discussion-between-gil9red-and-shaman888).